# when we have different results, can we say that logic is not universal?

Tags: logic

suppose we have to persons has the same level of experience and same equipments... we asked them to solve a problem, and it's almost clear that they'll have some differences in their solutions

i think of this example for a while and the only reason i found is that they don't have the same logic. But, isn't it universal?

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! If two people were asked to add 1+1 together, surely they would both answer two; one of them may be astute enough to ask 'two what? two vectors pointing in orthogonal directions won't add upto 2 in any fashion"; this is a problem of *typing* ie giving contextual information, which is simply presupposed - because we have to presuppose something to get a discussion or argument going.

Comment: Welcome to the philosophy SE. Sometimes an interesting question like the one you are asking already has an answer, so you can refer to the previous answers for your research. This question has already been asked, and here is the answer: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/31644/13808