# Is logic relative like Einstein's Special Relativity or is it absolute?

Tags: logic

Is logic relative like Einstein's Special Relativity or is it absolute? I am thinking it is absolute, but at the same time I am inclined to think that it's not as simple as you may think.

Comment: This question is not much more specific than "is mathematics invented or discovered". There is already enough material for both that and your question on this site and the internet.

Comment: There are different types of logic. Which type did you gave in mind? It is NOT the case logic is just logic. Here are some distinct types of so called logic: Aristotelian, Deontic, Modal, Mathematical, etc. There are several academic disciplines that use the same word LOGIC in different contexts: Philosophy, Psychology, Rhetoric, Law, Political science, Mathematics, Computer science, etc. Some terminology has the same spelling & pronunciation (it looks like the same word & sounds like the same word) but in reality it has a different  conceptual meaning in a specific subject matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is logic subjective?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31641/is-logic-subjective)

Comment: Einstein's Relativity is not "relative" in the sense you are alluding...

Comment: If logic is relative, how could we answer your question?

Comment: Well, hmph. As people approach the speed of thought, their capacity for reason *does* seem to get distorted; ask any meth-head...

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by 'absolute'? It's fair to say that logics are [formal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system), and to an extent, one can create a formal system and incorporate any definition, axiom, and logic one likes. In this way, logics are largely conventional.

Comment: I just wanna make a statement that feels so right for the topic I've treated myself to a steaming cuppa tea: Snow is white, like some clouds and dogs have tails, one each, unless you live near a nuclear test site, and *Deus Magnus Est* and the circle fetish nature seems to be struggling with.

Comment: I really like this Feynman lecture, 'Hardware Software & Heurustics' https://youtu.be/EKWGGDXe5MA where he argues that logic is a way of sorting incoming data, & lacks capacity for insight & innovation in *why* to sort things in a given way. You should read Hofstadter, like Godel Escher Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid, for the best Coherentist challenge to your Idealist & Absolutist view of logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely ... that logic is relative. Here's a scenario that my create an illusion that it is:

A likes hot and B likes cold.

A turns off the AC/turns on the heater while B turns on the AC/turns off the heater.

The *argument form* is *identical* (modus ponens will do the trick), but the *conclusions* are antipodal, contradictory to be precise. Both A and B are logical (focus on the *form*), but one can imagine ... A and B accusing each other of being ... God forbid ... *illogical*.

*Time* ... also ... complicates things, but it could simply be a *surrogate marker* for something else. Any (good) guesses?

Just for good measure ... did you know, *mirabile dictu*, closing down a main road may actually ease traffic congestion? Visit Wikipedia and have your mind blown!

Comment: You might like to read this challenge yo your views, framing 'opposites' as a language-game: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98365/life-and-death-as-one-and-the-same/98369#9836

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you misunderstand what is 'relative' about special relativity. The 'rules' of relativity, like the rules of logic, are fixed, not relative. The most obvious point of comparison between special relativity and logic is that both can be applied to provide a unifying insight across different frames of reference.

As for 'it' being 'not so simple as you may think', I suspect you are correct: nothing is as simple as my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In a broad sense, logic is absolute. The basic rules of reasoning - the law of identity, noncontradiction and excluded middle - seem to hold true across cultures and times. Two contradictory statements cannot both be true, and a thing is what it is.

However, in practice our logical thinking is shaped by our perspectives, experiences and biases. What we consider "logical" is influenced by our worldviews and mental models. In this sense, logic has a relative aspect. What is logical to one person may not be logical to another, depending on their frame of reference.

Then there is the fact that our logical systems - from Aristotelian logic to modern mathematical logic - are human constructs. They are useful tools, but not absolute truths of the universe. They are approximations that work well within certain bounds.

So in summary, while the basic principles of logic likely hold absolutely, our ability to apply logic and think logically is impaired by our relative, human perspectives. Furthermore, the logical systems we have devised are approximate and limited in certain ways.

The idea of relative logic versus absolute truth reminds me of theory of relativity! Some things are absolute - like the speed of light - while our perception of phenomena is relative to our frame of reference. Perhaps we can view logic in a similar way.

Does this help clarify the issue for you, my curious friend? Let me know if you have any other questions. I enjoy these thoughtful discussions!

Comment: "Your" theory of relativity, Mr. Einstein?

Comment: I argue the correct framing is intersubjective, not absolute: 'The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92058/the-unreasonable-ineffectiveness-of-mathematics-in-most-sciences/92064#92064

Comment: Not down voting, but a contradiction can be populated by two true statements. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/ and [non-classical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-classical_logic).

Comment: As for everything being itself, [Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus) argued that everything constantly changes and that nothing is ever itself again. This is captured by the aphorism "You can't step in the same river twice".

Comment: @JD - Almost like it was written by some kind of language model.

Comment: @Obie2.0 It does have an odd timbre which I'd otherwise attribute to ESL, but LLM would produce similar effects.

Comment: Leaving this here because it is an indictment against the respondent. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35868/user-spamming-chatbot-answers

Answer (score 0):

**Logic**

1. (Logic) the branch of philosophy concerned with analysing the patterns of reasoning by which a conclusion is properly drawn from a set of premises, without reference to meaning or context. See also formal logic, deduction4, induction4
2. (Logic) any particular formal system in which are defined axioms and rules of inference. Compare formal system, formal language
3. the system and principles of reasoning used in a specific field of study
4. a particular method of argument or reasoning
5. force or effectiveness in argument or dispute
6. reasoned thought or argument, as distinguished from irrationality
7. the relationship and interdependence of a series of events, facts, etc
8. (Logic) chop logic to use excessively subtle or involved logic or argument
9. (Computer Science) electronics computing
   a. the principles underlying the units in a computer system that perform arithmetical and logical operations. See also logic circuit
   b. (as modifier): a logic element.

---

So logic is also and essentially a natural capacity of the human brain, the result of natural selection over millions of years, possibly billions. So, in that sense, it is contingent on life itself, possibly life on Earth.

This also means that every human being has the same logic and that personal experience, training, learning, cannot affect this capacity. We can think of it in the same way we do languages. You can learn different languages, you can become more articulate, fluent, talkative etc. but your native linguistic capacity is not affected. Same for logic. You can invent any number of arguments or reasonings, you can create any number of mathematical theories, but your innate logical capacity is not affected.

Perhaps the question is whether there could be a better logic. Maybe yes, but then who is going to make it? Nobody on Earth is going to beat natural selection. No engineering company could come anywhere near emulating the process of natural selection.

So, maybe some Alien species somewhere in the universe got better logic, but maybe the snag is whether your logic is good for the kind of environment you live in. So better logic over there may not translate as better logic here on Earth. We are probably incapable of producing ourselves a better logic. We are aware of logic broadly since Aristotle 2,500 years ago and we still cannot produce a correct formal model of it, so improving on it would be not for any time soon.

So, logic is not absolute. It is contingent on life, or perhaps only on the kind of physics our universe has. Maybe there couldn't be any better logic than the one we have. It is easy to conceive of the possibility of the same logic implemented on a bigger and faster brain, in particular a machine, but improving on human deductive logic itself seems beyond even our power of imagination.

And for people who think that my view is irrational or somehow unfounded, this is not just me saying this. Here is what a research scientist from the Innovative Computing Laboratory (University of Tennessee) says about logic:

> Logic is inherent in the structure of neurons.

So, no, we cannot claim we know that this is true, but it is way more plausible than anything else, and indeed the only rational perspective to have on the subject given what we know about logic.

Comment: Just curious, why the down votes? I upvoted one. Seems a perfectly plausible position to say that logic is biologically or even historically contingent in at least its relative completeness, and in some sense "relative" to the spacetime framework of "consciousness," however that may be defined. An analogy might be Kant and nonEuclidean geometries. Anyway, I'll look at the question/answers cited by Conifold. Maybe the down voters explain themselves there.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander Maybe because of the lecturing style. Maybe because it is almost void of any references supporting the claims. Or, apart from these stylistic factors, because it seems to confuse an almost platonic account of **THE** logic (hardwired laws of thought) and a more nuanced account of the contextualisation of logic, which very much implies a plurality of problem-adjusted systems of logics as practiced by mathematicians/logicians. I refrained from voting, but I guess these are relevant factors

Comment: @NelsonAlexander Too much of this answer is simply false. It conflates logic with reasoning. Reasoning is what people do; logic is the study of the relationships of consequence between sentences. To claim that everyone has the same logic is so obviously incorrect that it barely needs comment. Likewise that human beings do not learn logic. Most people are poor at logic: it needs to be taught and learned. When it comes to reasoning with uncertainties, people are quite spectacularly bad at it. There has been a lot of progress in logic: Frege's logic is a vast improvement on Aristotle's, etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks, don't disagree, parts of it are indeed wrong, and I was casually over-generalizing, taking the main point to be biological-historical contingency.

Comment: @Bumble I don't conflate logic with reasoning. Logic is only a mode of reasoning. Further, it is mathematicians who conflate logic and formal logic, as if the word "formal" was there just because it is pretty rather than really meaningful. The word "logic" is polysemous. Most people are poor at formal logic, including mathematicians. But it is obvious that the human brain has a logical capacity just like it has a linguistic capacity.

Comment: @Speakpigeon With this fuzzy a concept, I question the viability of distinguishing between the capacities of logic and language, since both are about syntactic-semantical relations between conceptual units. And this, in turn,  seems to miss the meaning the OP had in mind

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Platonic account?! You think that the idea that logic is a product of natural selection is compatible with a Platonic account?! My answer couldn't be further from a Platonic account of logic and this is pretty obvious, too. I thought it was mathematicians who believed in a Platonic world of mathematical things..2. Your criticism of the lack of references is also fallacious. There are no references because there is no philosopher arguing like I do. Following your suggestion would lead to answers only reflecting this or that part of academia..

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking "*seems to miss the meaning the OP had in mind*" Care to support your opinion?

Comment: @Speakpigeon: Firstly, platonic meant the insistence on a unitary "logic" existing dispatched from any particular instances, with independent being and becoming. You can deny as much as you like, but that's how your post (1st part) reads. Secondly, if you want to post original thought, StackExchange sites are not the place to do so. That's because of how StackExchange works, not because we dislike outliers. Thirdly, I highlighted that there seems to be a shift in the middle of the post towards a more contextualised meaning of logic which, as I wrote, isn't far from language in general anymore.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking "*Firstly, platonic meant the insistence on a unitary "logic" existing dispatched from any particular instances, with independent being and becoming. You can deny as much as you like, but that's how your post (1st part) reads*" This is obviously completely absurd since my answer starts with this: "*So logic is also and essentially a natural capacity of the human brain, the result of natural selection*". Your insistence that my answer suggests a "Platonic" view of logic means that we can all from now on ignore everything you say.

Comment: @Speakpigeon If you think that saying that as something is a result of natural selection, it cannot be platonic in any sense, that's fine by me. I use the term in a broader sense than Plato did, obviously: Abstract universals treated as if we could speak about them as actual things. Like "logic" being the result of natural selection. I basically just urge you to be more careful in your wording (I don't even disagree on the point itself). If you are not able of charitable readings and disqualify peers, on the other hand, this is just rude and tells a lot about you, personally.